# Java 8 Compiler Confusion With overloaded methods

Tags: java, java-8, guava

While upgrading an app to Java 8 I ran into a weird issue with google guava's `newArrayList` in a couple of places.

Take a look at this example:

```
import com.google.common.collect.UnmodifiableIterator;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.google.common.collect.Iterators.forEnumeration;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

public class NewArrayListIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

        UnmodifiableIterator<?> elements = forEnumeration(getEnumeration().getAll());
        System.out.println("declarefirst = " + newArrayList(elements)); // calls newArrayList(Iterator<? extends E> elements)

        ArrayList directCopy = newArrayList(forEnumeration(getEnumeration().getAll()));
        System.out.println("useDirectly = " + directCopy); //calls newArrayList(E... elements)
    }

    public static Attribute getEnumeration(){
        return new BasicAttribute("foo",1);
    }
}
```

In the first example when I get the `UnmodifiableIterator` first into its own variable and then call `newArrayList` I get what I expect, which is the Iterators values copied into a new `List`.

In the second example where the `forEnumeration` goes directly into the `newArrayList` method I get back a `List` with a containing the iterator (which contains the value).

According to Intellij it *thinks* that both method calls should be to `newArrayList(Iterator<? extends E> elements)` but I found when debugging that the second call actually goes to `newArrayList(E... elements)`.

It only happens when I compile with the Oracle JDK8 targeted to Java8. If I target to 7 it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler thinks that `newArrayList(Iterator<? extends E>)` is not applicable (maybe because of [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051402)) and then silently chooses the generic varargs method which is *always* applicable (which shows the danger of such overload), when you don’t use a specific element type for your result list.

The bug appears with wildcard types, i.e. in your code it’s `Attribute.getAll()` returning a `NamingEnumeration<?>` hence the result of `forEnumeration` is `UnmodifiableIterator<?>` which the compiler refuses to assign to `Iterable<? extends E>`, the parameter type of `newArrayList`. If you cast the return value of the inner call to `Enumeration` the problem disappears as it does when you cast the return value of the outer call to `Iterator`.

I don’t see a simple short-term solution for this problem. After all, I don’t understand why you didn’t use `List<?> directCopy=Collections.list(getEnumeration().getAll());` in the first place…

Note that if you want to find all occurrences of this problem, you may simply use a patched version of guava in which `newArrayList(E...)` has been removed and check all compiler-errors (assuming you don’t have many case where you really want to call this overload). After rewriting the call sites, you may turn back to the original guava.

Comment: It's a large codebase with many authors. So I can't answer why one way was picked over another. I just need to find them all. Thanks for the tip on patching guava. I hadn't thought of doing that. I guess I know what I'm doing this morning.

Comment: The only problem with removing newArrayList(E...) is that once you do the compiler starts using the right one. So it looks like the only truly safe say is to quickly evaluate them all.

Comment: That’s strange as the reason for not using the right one is that the compiler thinks that the right one isn’t applicable and that shouldn’t change suddenly when the wrong one has been removed. When I tried the trick with Netbeans it worked as expected but it may be different with IntelliJ which, as you said, would pick up the right invocation target. But I thought that if IntelliJ and the underlying javac disagree, IntelliJ wouldn’t hide javac’s errors. Did it actually generate class files?

Comment: I was just compiling with maven and leaving intellij out of it

Comment: Seems to be a version issue. Just tested it with `1.8.0_20` where it produced an error and a beta `1.8.0_40` where it compiled. This is consistent: when being compiled with `1.8.0_40` without the varargs method being removed, it still invokes the right method.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen with overloaded methods and generic types. In this case the more generic version of `newArrayList()` is being chosen when the parameter is not explicitly typed.

I don't have a technical explanation for you, but I'd recommend you force usage of the desired method overload by casting:

```
ArrayList directCopy = newArrayList((Iterator)forEnumeration(getEnumeration().getAll()));
```

Comment: Ah but that means I have to find them all first!

Comment: Hehe bummer :/  That should be just a "find all references" since IntelliJ is correctly determining those right?

Comment: I would have thought but Intellij is being weird and giving me all of the variations back. Plus newArrayList(Iterator is quite common since it's often used in conjunction with Filter and such. So I need to go though them all and find the ones with the ambiguous generics (out of 600ish)